# Are these boards above my garage structural?

Tags: flooring, garage, joists, structural

I started laying out some plywood for storage above my garage, and was wondering id these 2x8's can be removed to make a flatter space.  I saw someone refer to them as "catwalks", though I can't find the reference now.  There are two of them, and they're basically a 2x4 nailed flat against the joists, and a 2x10 naild perpendicular to that.

There is nothing above except the roof, and the garage is below.  Total area is about 30x30'
[image]!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cat walk or rat walk is what we called them. We usually laid them flat and would staple the romex. 
They keep the boards from moving and cracking the Sheetrock, since you are decking the area make sure to do the same with the decking or as you move around it will damage the Sheetrock.

Comment: What do you mean by "make sure to do the same with the decking"?

Comment: @GregMiller, don't remove the boards until you have some decking to tie the joists together, and the decking needs to get screwed into every joist - don't skip any.  If you just removed the boards and then started to lay the decking, walking on the joists would cause them to move and rip out screw/nail holes in the drywall.  Basically, they are not "structural", but you do need something to keep the joists from moving and decking will do the job.

Comment: Jphi1618 , this is what I was trying to say , they keep the board from moving.  Unfortunately no other up votes./+